# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Instance package installation problems

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have an amazon EC2 installation of Ubuntu Precise 12.04, 64Bit (ami-ce7b6fba)

I just don't seem to be able to install anything as you would normally expect.  When I run 'sudo apt-get update' I get the following issues;

```
W: GPG error: http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 06E85760C0A52C50
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/andphe/php/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/andphe/php/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/andphe/php/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone assist me in getting this fixed?

Thank you so much in advance

Stu

Comment: why is it looking at www.ubnt.com?

Answer (score 0):

These links indeed do not exist. Did you change aptitude update sources by any chance?

If that's the failure of these particular PPAs then the normal updates should work nevertheless.
Try changing sources in **/etc/apt/sources.list** to something less radical, like

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

You should also run an autoclean to reload the public key for the PPA source (if it exists at all)

```
$ apt-get autoclean
$ apt-get update
```